WorkerExtensions.csproj in user's Temp folder continue building, burning hard disk space
It seem that this is related to Azure functions. I have a build machine where builds are performed. And hard disk space has been disappearing. I found that one of the culprits are folders like this  C:\Users\someUser\AppData\Local\Temp\hg02d4sd.p1z. I have 22 daily instances of this type of folder. Some larger than others - from 25 to 130Mb. Contents of these folders look like a .net project folder with the following contents

obj
publishout
WorkerExtensions.csproj

The output of this project is Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
        <AssemblyName>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions</AssemblyName>
        <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" Version="3.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="_VerifyTargetFramework" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <!-- It is possible to override our TFM via global properties. This can lead to successful builds, but runtime errors due to incompatible dependencies being brought in. -->
        <Error Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0'" Text="The target framework '$(TargetFramework)' must be 'net6.0'. Verify if target framework has been overridden by a global property." />
    </Target>
</Project>

BTW, the project files are different - these have different references. Another project has this
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" Version="3.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.16.1" />
</ItemGroup> 

I am trying to understand what is going on. Is this related to me building Azure functions on this machine? Or this is some application that is installed on this box doing it?
I found this wonderful page. Not sure if this related to this at all. I don't have any
services on the box that says "Azure"
I would appreciate some tip here, pointing me in the right direction.
update: It does seem that building azure functions creates these folders. I see the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll in the output (dotnet publish dir) of Azure function projects. But not sure how does it work and if it is possible to setup cleanup using proj file or some other configuration.

@T.S., Is this isolated function or In-process?

@PravallikaKV Because our project (I am not developer of this) has Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker and Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk, I assume this is isolated. I think I know where this conversation goes to. however, I can't find how to deal with it on configuration level if possible at all. I've seen some info from github... Still researching. But may be you know something
